# Make last hovered menu item stay open

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have a menu that when hovered, shows the subnav of the current hovered item by adding `.stick` to the submenu and removing it on mouseleave. If not hovering on another menu item I want the last hovered menu item to stay open for another 2 seconds before hiding.

Here's what I have. I know that the `mouseleave()` called on the container won't work since it's within the handlerOut of the `ul#main-nav > li` hover function but I left it to show you where I last left off.

```
$('ul#main-nav > li').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(window.menustick);
    $this.find('ul.submenu').addClass('stick');
}, function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.siblings().hover()) {
        $this.find('ul.submenu').removeClass('stick');
    } else if ($('#main-nav').mouseleave()) {
        window.menustick = setTimeout(function(){
            $this.find('ul.submenu').removeClass('stick');
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

**[Here's the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemiketm09/3F7bJ/)**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Hi @Dom, [Here's the JS Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemiketm09/3F7bJ/) Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the JS Fiddle, check it out http://jsfiddle.net/3F7bJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of issues with your scripts and CSS.

Firstly, your CSS had the following rule:

```
nav ul#main-nav li:hover > ul.submenu {
   display: block;
}
```

This needs to be modified to:

```
nav ul#main-nav li > ul.submenu.stick {
     display: block;
}
```

This meant that your CSS was controlling the visibility rather than the class 'stick'.

As you mentioned the use of `.hover()` and `.mouseleave()` in the script code is incorrect and not required. As at that point you are already in the `mouseleave` (handlerOut) of the `hover`.

The below code appears to perform the desired effect you were looking for:

```
var menuStickTimeoutId;
$('ul#main-nav > li').hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(menuStickTimeoutId);
    $('#main-nav ul.submenu').removeClass('stick');
    $this.find('ul.submenu').addClass('stick');
}, function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(menuStickTimeoutId);
    menuStickTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        $this.find('ul.submenu').removeClass('stick');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/3F7bJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
 $("ul#main-nav > li").hover(
    function(){
      $(this).children('ul').hide().fadeIn(500);
    },
    function () {
        $('ul.submenu', this).fadeOut(2000);            
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3F7bJ/3/